# how to delete user if user doesnot attempt login within 30 days in php

Tags: php

i am new in php.. i want to delete the user automatically if he does not attempt login in 30 days.

```
for example
if user login on "10-02-2012" , 
and if user doesnot login for next 30 days
then system should automatically delete his account. 

if user again login on "15-02-2012" ,
then limit should be for next 30 days i-e "15-03-2012"
```

please help me i am very new in php

```
i have no idea how to store the date when user attempt to login.
```

Comment: to accept answers you must have repute greater than 15.  @sudhir

Comment: @Jassi, not required, only one reputation point is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You want to have a date field in the user table and a query that sets that date to CURDATE() whenever your login script runs. Something like:

   UPDATE 'users' SET 'lastlogin' = CURDATE() WHERE 'userid' = '$userid';
2. Have a crontab that runs once a day (or however often you want) that queries all the fields that are 31 days old and deletes them:

   DELETE FROM 'users' WHERE 'lastlogin' < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 31 DAY

Comment: A script that runs automatically periodically (like monthly or daily). Most hosts have a way to set one up in their control panel. It requires that you know the server path (not the url) to your script. You can find that by temporarily printing $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] somewhere in the script. If a crontab is not an option, a less ideal option is to let #2 piggyback on another script, like the login script, so it deletes the old users whenever someone logs in. This is less ideal because it may run more frequently than you need or not frequently enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log the last login date in a Database.
2. Write a script which searches and deletes users where the last login was more then 30 days ago.
3. start the search and delete script with a cron job

Comment: @maham A scrip which is executed automaticly at certain times. This is NOT PHP specific and if you want to do server side coding I recoment you google it and read a bit about it. Crinjobs are VERY handy for tasks like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial on building a login system:
http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Your solution would add to the tutorial by adding a DATETIME field named "last_login" to the members table. Whenever someone logs in, you update the last_login field with a database query like:

```
UPDATE TABLE members SET last_login = CURRENT_TIME WHERE id = xxx LIMIT 1
```

Then you can run another database query once a day to delete inactive accounts, customizing the deletion date as needed:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE members WHERE last_login < '2012-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple.

1. create a field in the DB table that stores the most recent login date.
2. write a script run every night at midnight that checks the login date against the current date.

the great thing about this is date objects allow you to easily compare dates easily.

here are some links that will help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

best of luck! it's pretty straight forward I have done it many times im sure you wont have much trouble.

Comment: how to write script that runs automatically everyday

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+run+a+cron+job&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=how%20to%20run%20a%20cron%20job&cp=6&gs_id=1p&xhr=t&q=cron+job&pf=p&client=firefox-a&hs=sBV&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=cron+j&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d7cb668c3d121159&biw=1367&bih=945

Answer (score 0):

In your data base, where user accounts are stored, you can store the last time they logged in using one of the built in MySQL date/time data types. In your PHP you can update this to the current time with another MySQL command. This page will get you started: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

As for deleting a user, you will want to set up a cron job/scheduled task, that will delete this user by checking the date and seeing if it is 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two field for users table

1. `created` : date when user registered
2. `login_date`: date update on every login by user.

And you can use cron Job which run automatically (run a php file which path set in it) on selected time. you can run it every day on a fixed time. and if found both `created` and `login_date` same then delete that user from database. You can set cron job from your cpanel.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

set up cron job for once a day and check who didn't logged in from last 30 days to current time / date you can use timestamp or date for last login